# using /setblock to place a colored bed in Minecraft 1.12

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I tried placing a white bed using the setblock command, like I did below

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ bed 0
```

I used "0" because that's the data value for a white bed. But this did not work and it only placed half of a red bed.
I don't know if this is a bug or what please explain the correct to do this using only command blocks to place a full colored bed in Minecraft 1.12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after searching around the internet for a while I found out beds do have an NBT tag for color in 1.12 this command worked for me:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ bed 0 destroy {color:0}
```

of course that only placed half a bed for me so I had to follow up with:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ bed 8 destroy {color:0}
```

to change the color you only have to change the zero to a different number between 0 and 15

Answer (score 1):

The bed consists of two blocks, so of course you need to specify both. To get the data value for the other half, or any information about 1.12.2, you can always just look at past versions of Minecraft wiki pages, like here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Bed&oldid=1162371#Block_data

Comment: So do I have to specify both the color AND direction for the second half, or is just direction enough?

Comment: @Quijibo There is no bed color in 1.12

Comment: My bad, I got confused by the title "using /setblock to place a _colored_ bed in Minecraft 1.12"

Comment: @Ferrybig Beds did have colour in 1.12.2, it was added it 17w15a.

Comment: @Quijibo Of course you have to specify the colour, because the ID is "white_bed", "red_bed" etc. A block called "bed" no longer exists.

Comment: I could not find the data value for a white bed in this link.

Comment: It's in the comment right above yours.

Comment: I am _very_ confused from these comments right now.

Comment: **/setblock ~ ~ ~ white_bed** Or just look at the wiki or use Google.